# javascript change select time when choice is change

Tags: javascript, select, addeventlistener

i have an choice where the element inside are generate by php (and can change everyday).
i would like to change an other select(time) when my first select change.
My first select is a choice where the value is the time at start and at end.
My second select is a choice wwith the time between start and stop.

when my page is load i must to override the select.

My probleme is for change **the value a second time** .

```js
//select service
var serviceCheck = document.getElementById("order_openname");
var hoursSelect = document.getElementById("order_ready_at_hours");

var serviceValue = serviceCheck.value;
var serviceValueHourStart = serviceValue.substring(0, 2);
var serviceValueMinuteStart = serviceValue.substring(3, 5);
var serviceValueHourStop = serviceValue.substring(9, 11);
var serviceValueMinuteStop = serviceValue.substring(12, 15);

// change select at start

var select = document.createElement("select");
select.name = "order[ready_at][hours]";
select.classList.add("form-control");
hoursSelect.replaceWith(select, hoursSelect);
hoursSelect.remove();
for (serviceValueHourStart; serviceValueHourStart < serviceValueHourStop; serviceValueHourStart++) {
    var addHours = String(serviceValueHourStart);

    var option = document.createElement("option");

    option.text = addHours;
    select.add(option);
    
}
// change select when service is change

serviceCheck.addEventListener('change', function () {
    serviceValue = serviceCheck.value;
    serviceValueHourStart = serviceValue.substring(0, 2);
    serviceValueMinuteStart = serviceValue.substring(3, 5);
    serviceValueHourStop = serviceValue.substring(9, 11);
    serviceValueMinuteStop = serviceValue.substring(12, 15);


    if (select) {

        var selectHours = document.createElement("select");
        selectHours.name = "order[ready_at][hours]";
        selectHours.classList.add("form-control");
        select.replaceWith(selectHours, select);
        select.remove();

        for (serviceValueHourStart; serviceValueHourStart < serviceValueHourStop; serviceValueHourStart++) {
            addHours = String(serviceValueHourStart);

            option = document.createElement("option");

            option.text = addHours;
            selectHours.add(option);
         
        }


    }
    })
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="required" for="order_openname">Service :</label>
<select id="order_openname" name="order[openname]" class="form-control">
<option value="11:01:00|15:01:00">Morning</option>
<option value="18:01:00|22:01:00">Afternoon</option></select></div>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
           <legend class="col-form-label required">Order for :</legend>
<div id="order_ready_at" class="form-inline"><div class="col-auto">
                <label class="required" for="order_ready_at_hours">Hours</label>
                <select id="order_ready_at_hours" name="order[ready_at][hours]" class="form-control"><option value="1">0</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option value="3">2</option>
<option value="4">3</option>
<option value="5">4</option>
<option value="6">5</option>
<option value="7">6</option>
<option value="8">7</option>
<option value="9">8</option>
<option value="10">9</option>
<option value="11">10</option>
<option value="12">11</option>
<option value="13">12</option>
<option value="14">13</option>
<option value="15">14</option>
<option value="16">15</option>
<option value="17">16</option>
<option value="18">17</option>
<option value="19">18</option>
<option value="20">19</option>
<option value="21">20</option>
<option value="22">21</option>
<option value="23">22</option>
<option value="24">23</option>
</select>
            </div>
```

If you know a better solution or if you can explain me how can did for change my select more than two time thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```js
//select service
var serviceCheck = document.getElementById("order_openname");
var hoursSelect = document.getElementById("order_ready_at_hours");
  
var serviceValue = serviceCheck.value;
var serviceValueHourStart = serviceValue.substring(0, 2);
var serviceValueMinuteStart = serviceValue.substring(3, 5);
var serviceValueHourStop = serviceValue.substring(9, 11);
var serviceValueMinuteStop = serviceValue.substring(12, 15);
  

var select = document.createElement("select");
select.name = "order[ready_at][hours]";
select.classList.add("form-control");
select.id = "order_ready_at_hours";
hoursSelect.replaceWith(select, hoursSelect);
hoursSelect.remove();
for (serviceValueHourStart; serviceValueHourStart < serviceValueHourStop; serviceValueHourStart++) {
    var addHours = String(serviceValueHourStart);

    var option = document.createElement("option");

    option.text = addHours;
    select.add(option);

}
// change select when service is change

serviceCheck.addEventListener('change', function () {
    serviceValue = serviceCheck.value;
    serviceValueHourStart = serviceValue.substring(0, 2);
    serviceValueMinuteStart = serviceValue.substring(3, 5);
    serviceValueHourStop = serviceValue.substring(9, 11);
    serviceValueMinuteStop = serviceValue.substring(12, 15);


    var selectTime = document.getElementById("order_ready_at_hours");

    var selectHours = document.createElement("select");
    selectHours.name = "order[ready_at][hours]";
    selectHours.classList.add("form-control");
    selectHours.id =  "order_ready_at_hours";
    selectTime.replaceWith(selectHours, selectTime);
    selectTime.remove();

    for (serviceValueHourStart; serviceValueHourStart < serviceValueHourStop; serviceValueHourStart++) {
        addHours = String(serviceValueHourStart);

        option = document.createElement("option");

        option.text = addHours;
        selectHours.add(option);

    }


})
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="required" for="order_openname">Service :</label>
<select id="order_openname" name="order[openname]" class="form-control">
<option value="11:01:00|15:01:00">Morning</option>
<option value="18:01:00|22:01:00">Afternoon</option></select></div>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
           <legend class="col-form-label required">Order for :</legend>
<div id="order_ready_at" class="form-inline"><div class="col-auto">
                <label class="required" for="order_ready_at_hours">Hours</label>
                <select id="order_ready_at_hours" name="order[ready_at][hours]" class="form-control"><option value="1">0</option>
<option value="2">1</option>
<option value="3">2</option>
<option value="4">3</option>
<option value="5">4</option>
<option value="6">5</option>
<option value="7">6</option>
<option value="8">7</option>
<option value="9">8</option>
<option value="10">9</option>
<option value="11">10</option>
<option value="12">11</option>
<option value="13">12</option>
<option value="14">13</option>
<option value="15">14</option>
<option value="16">15</option>
<option value="17">16</option>
<option value="18">17</option>
<option value="19">18</option>
<option value="20">19</option>
<option value="21">20</option>
<option value="22">21</option>
<option value="23">22</option>
<option value="24">23</option>
</select>
            </div>
```